# blank line added with writerow function to a csv file

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to write in a CSV file using this code:

```
with open('tri.csv', 'a') as csvfile2:
    writer0 = csv.writer(csvfile2, delimiter=';', encoding='utf-8')
    writer0.writerow([id_emp, name_emp, old_date, "", "", "", old_diff])
```

but when I open the `tri.csv` file I find that it adds a blank line after every line.

Why is that?

Comment: Does `old_diff` contain a newline at the end?

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: If you are using Python 2.x use `'ab'` in your `open()`. If you are using Python 3.x add `newline=''` as another parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python 2.x use `'ab'` in your `open()`. If you are using Python 3.x add `newline=''` as another parameter. This is recommended in the [`csv.writer()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) documentation. For example:

Python 2.x

```
with open('tri.csv', 'ab') as csvfile2:
    writer0 = csv.writer(csvfile2, delimiter=';', encoding='utf-8')
    writer0.writerow([id_emp, name_emp, old_date, "", "", "", old_diff])
```

Python 3.x

```
with open('tri.csv', 'a', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile2:
    writer0 = csv.writer(csvfile2, delimiter=';')
    writer0.writerow([id_emp, name_emp, old_date, "", "", "", old_diff])
```

Note, by making this change it will remove **additional** blank lines between rows. `writerow()` will always add a newline at the end which is usually required. To stop it from writing that, you would need a different approach that first writes the data to a string not a file, strip the newline and then write the resulting text to a file.

See also: [Python CSV insert final newline - how can I avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48192161/4985733)